# What to do with over cooked quince jam

Tags: jam

I ended up overcooking my quince jam. It is really overcooked. It's not burned or anything but the quince pieces have harden up due to loss of water. Can I use it for something else? I don't wanna through it as it would be 6Kg of waste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider making your own [membrillo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quince_cheese).

> Quince cheese, also known as dulce de membrillo, is a sweet, thick, jelly made of the pulp of the quince fruit. Quince cheese is a common confection in several countries, where it goes by various names, such as [. . .]

It's a really great option and pairs beautifully with cheese and crackers. I've never made it before but there are some guides on the web and, considering it's essentially a very dense jelly, it may be ok with your dense quince fruits.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I ended up mincing the quince pieces. I had to warm them up first. and made a very thick past which is just yum. I bottled the syrup which can last a life. I heard it is a remedy for diarrhea. But I gonna make some kumquat brandy liquor and will use some of the syrup instead of sugar.